# Http post in angular 7 returns invalid response

Tags: http, angular7

I am using http post for one of my angular application for login.I have checked the url with the params in postman which gives me the output.But when i try to use the same in the application i am getting the error as invalid login all the time.
I would like to know whether the way i pass the params are correct or not?

```
const formData =  `username=${username}&password=${password}`;
const options = { headers: new Headers({ 'Content-Type': 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded' }) };
return this.http.post<any>(`${this.baseUrl}?action=login&`, formData, options)
        .pipe(map(response => {
            console.log('user is', response);
            if (response && response.session && response.session.id) {
                localStorage.setItem('currentUser', JSON.stringify(response));
                this.currentUserSubject.next(response);
            }

            return response;
        }));
```

The error i am getting is

```
user is {error: "Incorrect Login."}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try like this instead of formData

```
const data = new HttpParams()
    .set('username', username)
    .set('password', password);

return this.http.post<any>(`${this.baseUrl}?action=login&`, data)
        .pipe(map(response => {
            if (response.status === 'success') {
                localStorage.setItem('currentUser', JSON.stringify(response));
                this.currentUserSubject.next(response);
            }

            return response;
        }));
```